# "ValueError: Write disposition WRITE_EMPTY is not supported for streaming inserts to BigQuery"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using WriteToBigQuery in a beam python pipeline like this:

```
beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
    table_id,
    schema=table_schema,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_EMPTY,
    method='STREAMING_INSERTS')
```

But when I run the pipeline, I am seeing this erorr, which occurred after I fetched and rebased from the beam GitHub master branch today.

```
"ValueError: Write disposition WRITE_EMPTY is not supported for streaming inserts to BigQuery"
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a recent change, intentionally disabled this due to a bug. So `write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_EMPTY` is no longer allowed with `method='STREAMING_INSERTS'`

The fix is to now use `write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND` which should give the same behaviour.

```
beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
    table_id,
    schema=table_schema,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    method='STREAMING_INSERTS')
```